# Python 3 will not print out all the output without pressing enter again

Tags: python

```
from random import shuffle
numberOfTestCase = int(input())

for i in range(numberOfTestCase):

    listLength = int(input())
    aList = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    sumList = 0
    for x in range(listLength):
        sumList = aList[x] + sumList

    if sumList == 0:
        print("NO")
    else:
        #shuffle(aList)
        print("YES")
        #print(' '.join(map(str, aList)))
        print(aList)
```

when i have 4 test cases why does it only return 3 of them?

Comment: 4
4
1 -2 3 -4
3
0 0 0
5
1 -1 1 -1 1
6
40 -31 -9 0 13 -40

Comment: add what output you got and what you want to get.

Comment: @MaheshAnakali `range(4)` means 0 to 3, so there are 4 items in it.

Comment: Each time you call `input()`, it will prompt for an input until you press enter. Is this the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for pressing enter before the output is displayed is the `input` function. You have 2 input functions for each of the first `input` case numbers chosen.
I don't see a problem with the number of cases. Please elaborate in case this is not what you meant.
I also do not think that you have a problem with the range function here since it is serving its purpose by iterating through the number of cases and list numbers.

Here is an example of 4 inputs with what is happening in your code:

```
4
1
1
[1]
the item index to be added is 0 while the item is 1
YES
[1]
2
0 0
[0, 0]
the item index to be added is 0 while the item is 0
the item index to be added is 1 while the item is 0
NO
3
6 4 3
[6, 4, 3]
the item index to be added is 0 while the item is 6
the item index to be added is 1 while the item is 4
the item index to be added is 2 while the item is 3
YES
[6, 4, 3]
4
9 2 1 -5
[9, 2, 1, -5]
the item index to be added is 0 while the item is 9
the item index to be added is 1 while the item is 2
the item index to be added is 2 while the item is 1
the item index to be added is 3 while the item is -5
YES
[9, 2, 1, -5]
```

Comment: thank you for the response， the input is consist of 7 lines.

Comment: the fist line is a integer indicating how many inputs there is

Comment: second line is a single integer indcating how many number of the first input list(ie 4)

Comment: third line is a list(for the sake of this exsample it is 4 numbers) ie 1 -2 -3 4

Comment: then the fourth to seventh line is repeating second to third step with different number/lists